# What are the extra weapon/trap slots for?

Tags: orcs-must-die

In *Orcs Must Die!*, in both the spellbook and upgrade page, there are extra slots left over after finishing the story on War Mage, and after playing through a few levels of Nightmare mode, it doesn't seem that there are any new traps/weapons coming.

Are these spare slots left there for future DLC, or is there a way to unlock these new weapons that I'm just missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are just spare slots. The items doesn't exist yet, and are most likely to be included in future updates or DLC.

Comment: Any source before I accept?

Comment: @MrSmooth I can't site a source regarding the DLC comment, but I can verify that there's nothing new that you will get beyond what you received in the War Mage campaign. Those spots are currently just there for looks.

Comment: http://www.robotentertainment.com/blog/detail/Harness-Artifacts-Power-new-OMD-DLC